# Javascript error after upgrade to Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, drupal-7

I posted a similar question at the Drupal Forum, but I haven't had much luck.
I'm upgrading a site from D6 to D7. So far it's gone well, but I'm getting a Javascript error that I just can't pin down a solution for.
This is a cut down version of the whole script:

```
(function($) {
function sign(secret, message) {
var messageBytes = str2binb(message);
var secretBytes = str2binb(secret);
if (secretBytes.length > 16) {
secretBytes = core_sha256(secretBytes, secret.length * chrsz);
}
var ipad = Array(16), opad = Array(16);
for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) { 
ipad[i] = secretBytes[i] ^ 0x36363636;
opad[i] = secretBytes[i] ^ 0x5C5C5C5C;
}
var imsg = ipad.concat(messageBytes);
var ihash = core_sha256(imsg, 512 + message.length * chrsz);
var omsg = opad.concat(ihash);
var ohash = core_sha256(omsg, 512 + 256); 
var b64hash = binb2b64(ohash);
var urlhash = encodeURIComponent(b64hash);
return urlhash;
}

function addZero(n) {
return ( n < 0 || n > 9 ? "" : "0" ) + n;
}

Date.prototype.toISODate =
new Function("with (this)\nreturn " +
"getFullYear()+'-'+addZero(getMonth()+1)+'-'" +
"+addZero(getDate())+'T'+addZero(getHours())+':'" +
"+addZero(getMinutes())+':'+addZero(getSeconds())+'.000Z'");

function getNowTimeStamp() {
var time = new Date();
var gmtTime = new Date(time.getTime() + (time.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
return gmtTime.toISODate() ;
}
}(jQuery));
```

The part that keeps throwing an error I'm seeing in Firebug is at:

```
Date.prototype.toISODate =
new Function("with (this)\n    return " +
"getFullYear()+'-'+addZero(getMonth()+1)+'-'" +
"+addZero(getDate())+'T'+addZero(getHours())+':'" +
"+addZero(getMinutes())+':'+addZero(getSeconds())+'.000Z'");
```

Firebug keeps stopping at "addZero is not defined". JS has never been my strong point, and I know some changes have been made in D7. I've already wrapped the entire script in "(function($) { }(jQuery));", but I must be missing something else. The same script works perfectly on the D6 site.

Here is the "fixed" version of the whole code with @Pointy suggestion added. All I left out is the part of the script for making the hash that goes to Amazon, and some of my declared variables.

```
(function($) {
var typedText;
var strSearch = /asin:/;
var srchASIN;
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#edit-field-game-title-und-0-asin").change(function() {
         typedText = $("#edit-field-game-title-und-0-asin").val();
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {typedText: typedText},
            dataType: 'text',
            url: '/asin/autocomplete/',
            success:function(){
               document.getElementById('asin-lookup').style.display='none';
               x = typedText.search(strSearch);
               y = (x+5);
               srchASIN = typedText.substr(y,10)
               amazonSearch();
            }
         });
      });  

      $("#search_asin").click(function() {
         $("#edit-field-game-title-und-0-asin").val('');
         document.getElementById('name-lookup').style.display='none';
         $("#edit-field-game-title-und-0-asin").val('');
         $("#edit-title").val('');
         $("#edit-field-subtitle-und-0-value").val('');
         $("#edit-field-game-edition-und-0-value").val('');
         $("#edit-field-release-date-und-0-value-date").val('');
         $("#edit-field-asin-und-0-asin").val('');
         $("#edit-field-ean-und-0-value").val('');
         $("#edit-field-amazon-results-und-0-value").val('');
         $("#edit-body").val('');
         srchASIN = $("#field-asin-enter").val();
         amazonSearch();
      });

      $("#clear_search").click(function() {
         $("#field-asin-enter").val(''); 
         $("#edit-field-game-title-und-0-asin").val('');
         $("#edit-title").val('');
         $("#edit-field-subtitle-und-0-value").val('');
         $("#edit-field-game-edition-und-0-value").val('');
         $("#edit-field-release-date-und-0-value-date").val('');
         $("#edit-field-release-dt2-und-0-value-date").val('');
         $("#edit-field-asin-und-0-asin").val('');
         $("#edit-field-ean-und-0-value").val('');
         $("#edit-field-amazon-results-und-0-value").val('');
         $("#field-amazon-platform").val('');
         $("#field-amazon-esrb").val('');
         $("#edit-body-und-0-value").val('');
         document.getElementById('asin-lookup').style.display='';
         document.getElementById('name-lookup').style.display='';
      });

      function amazonSearch(){
         var ASIN = srchASIN;
         var azScr = cel("script");
         azScr.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
         var requestUrl = invokeRequest(ASIN);
         azScr.setAttribute("src", requestUrl);
         document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(azScr);
      }
   });

var amzJSONCallback = function(tmpData){
   if(tmpData.Item){
      var tmpItem = tmpData.Item;
   }
   $("#edit-title").val(tmpItem.title);
   $("#edit-field-game-edition-und-0-value").val(tmpItem.edition);
   $("#edit-field-release-date-und-0-value-date").val(tmpItem.relesdate);
   $("#edit-field-release-dt2-und-0-value-date").val(tmpItem.relesdate);
   $("#edit-field-asin-und-0-asin").val(tmpItem.asin);
   $("#edit-field-ean-und-0-value").val(tmpItem.ean);
   $("#field-amazon-platform").val(tmpItem.platform);
   $("#field-amazon-publisher").val(tmpItem.publisher);
   $("#field-amazon-esrb").val(tmpItem.esrb); 
};
function ctn(x){ return document.createTextNode(x); }
function cel(x){ return document.createElement(x); }
function addEvent(obj,type,fn){
   if (obj.addEventListener){obj.addEventListener(type,fn,false);}
   else if (obj.attachEvent){obj["e"+type+fn]=fn; obj.attachEvent("on"+type,function(){obj["e"+type+fn]();});}
}

var styleXSL = "http://www.tlthost.net/sites/vglAmazonAsin.xsl";
function invokeRequest(ASIN) {
  cleanASIN = ASIN.replace(/[-' ']/g,'');
  var unsignedUrl = "http://xml-us.amznxslt.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&AssociateTag=theliterarytimes&IdType=ASIN&ItemId="+cleanASIN+"&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Medium,ItemAttributes,OfferFull&Style="+styleXSL+"&ContentType=text/javascript&CallBack=amzJSONCallback";
    var lines = unsignedUrl.split("\n");
    unsignedUrl = "";
    for (var i in lines) { unsignedUrl += lines[i]; }
  // find host and query portions
  var urlregex = new RegExp("^http:\\/\\/(.*)\\/onca\\/xml\\?(.*)$");
  var matches = urlregex.exec(unsignedUrl);
  var host = matches[1].toLowerCase();
  var query = matches[2];
  // split the query into its constituent parts
  var pairs = query.split("&");
  // remove signature if already there
  // remove access key id if already present 
  //  and replace with the one user provided above
  // add timestamp if not already present
  pairs = cleanupRequest(pairs);
  // encode the name and value in each pair
  pairs = encodeNameValuePairs(pairs);
  // sort them and put them back together to get the canonical query string
  pairs.sort();
  var canonicalQuery = pairs.join("&");
  var stringToSign = "GET\n" + host + "\n/onca/xml\n" + canonicalQuery;
  // calculate the signature
  //var secret = getSecretAccessKey();
  var signature = sign(secret, stringToSign);
  // assemble the signed url
  var signedUrl = "http://" + host + "/onca/xml?" + canonicalQuery + "&Signature=" + signature;
  //document.write ("<html><body><pre>REQUEST: "+signedUrl+"</pre></body></html>");
  return signedUrl;
}

function encodeNameValuePairs(pairs) {
  for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
  var name = "";
  var value = "";
  var pair = pairs[i];
  var index = pair.indexOf("=");
  // take care of special cases like "&foo&", "&foo=&" and "&=foo&" 
  if (index == -1) {
    name = pair;
  } else if (index == 0) {
     value = pair;
  } else {
    name = pair.substring(0, index);
    if (index < pair.length - 1) {
      value = pair.substring(index + 1);
    }
  }
    // decode and encode to make sure we undo any incorrect encoding
  name = encodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(name));
    value = value.replace(/\+/g, "%20");
  value = encodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(value));
  pairs[i] = name + "=" + value;
  }   
  return pairs;
}

function cleanupRequest(pairs) {
  var haveTimestamp = false;
    var haveAwsId = false;
  var nPairs = pairs.length;
  var i = 0;
  while (i < nPairs) {
  var p = pairs[i];
  if (p.search(/^Timestamp=/) != -1) {
    haveTimestamp = true;
  } else if (p.search(/^(AWSAccessKeyId|SubscriptionId)=/) != -1) {
    pairs.splice(i, 1, "AWSAccessKeyId=" + accessKeyId);
      haveAwsId = true;
  } else if (p.search(/^Signature=/) != -1) {
    pairs.splice(i, 1);
    i--;
    nPairs--;
  }
    i++;
  }
  if (!haveTimestamp) {
    pairs.push("Timestamp=" + getNowTimeStamp());
  }
    if (!haveAwsId) {
      pairs.push("AWSAccessKeyId=" + accessKeyId);
    }
    return pairs;
}

function sign(secret, message) {
  var messageBytes = str2binb(message);
  var secretBytes = str2binb(secret);
  if (secretBytes.length > 16) {
    secretBytes = core_sha256(secretBytes, secret.length * chrsz);
  }  
  var ipad = Array(16), opad = Array(16);
  for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) { 
    ipad[i] = secretBytes[i] ^ 0x36363636;
    opad[i] = secretBytes[i] ^ 0x5C5C5C5C;
  }
  var imsg = ipad.concat(messageBytes);
  var ihash = core_sha256(imsg, 512 + message.length * chrsz);
  var omsg = opad.concat(ihash);
  var ohash = core_sha256(omsg, 512 + 256);   
  var b64hash = binb2b64(ohash);
  var urlhash = encodeURIComponent(b64hash);
  return urlhash;
}

Date.prototype.toISODate = function() {
  function addZero(n) {
   return ( n < 0 || n > 9 ? "" : "0" ) + n;
  }
  var d = this;
  return d.getFullYear() + '-' + 
    addZero(d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' +
    addZero(d.getDate()) + 'T' +
    addZero(d.getHours()) + ':' +
    addZero(d.getMinutes()) + ':' +
    addZero(d.getSeconds()) + '.000Z';
};

  function getNowTimeStamp() {
      var time = new Date();
      var gmtTime = new Date(time.getTime() + (time.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
      return gmtTime.toISODate() ;
  }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: What does the error in the console say?

Comment: I tried to simplify the function by removing the stringiness - concatenation inside concatenation hurts my brain more than Inception. http://jsfiddle.net/ExvRS/ I get a undef on the inner functions, maybe check those are defined and imported, and also ready at the time they are called.

Comment: That's terrifying. Why is it written that way?

Comment: I didn't know you could do that... "Function objects created with the Function constructor are parsed when the function is created. This is less efficient than declaring a function and calling it within your code, because functions declared with the function statement are parsed with the rest of the code." -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: Using 'with' is bad practice. Actually causes worse performance.

Comment: @Aram: I really do stink at JS, so this was cobbled together from many different scripts. This whole this is used in an entry form on my Drupal site, The form starts with a ASIN/ISBN field that the user inserts the ASIN/ISBN of the game or book, then click the Auto Fill button. The JS works with a XSL file to filter the returned search, then automatically fills in most of the form with the returned results. It all worked fine on the Drupal 6 site, but it wouldn't work at all on D7. The fix below from Pointy helped.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better version of your code:

```
Date.prototype.toISODate = function() {
  function addZero(n) {
   return ( n < 0 || n > 9 ? "" : "0" ) + n;
  }
  var d = this;
  return d.getFullYear() + '-' + 
    addZero(d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' +
    addZero(d.getDate()) + 'T' +
    addZero(d.getHours()) + ':' +
    addZero(d.getMinutes()) + ':' +
    addZero(d.getSeconds()) + '.000Z';
};
```

That moves "addDate" inside the extension function, and it avoids the horrid `with` statement.

Comment: Thank you! That actually moved things along. Like I said, JS is not my strong point.

Comment: The script is now getting all the way to the end, but it still throws an error. It's getting the returned results from Amazon, but now the error says "amzJSONCallback is not defined". I can actually see the returned results.
I'd post the whole script but it's 390 lines long.

Comment: I just added the fixed version of the script. I swear I've run into the "amzJSONCallback is not defined" error before, but I can't remember how I fixed it.

Comment: It looks like you're talking to a JSONP interface, and you're sending it that function name as the callback. That means that there needs to be a **global** function with that name. If you've wrapped that declaration inside a jQuery "ready" handler, it won't be global. Try changing the definition to `window.amzJSONCallback = ...`  and see if that helps.

Comment: Halleluiah you did it @Pointy! That jQuery "ready" handler is what started the problems. Drupal 7 seems to need it, but it changed the way the script worked when I added it. I have no problems with PHP, but I still need to learn too much about JS. Thanks again.